# JWplayer not loading in ie 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, flash

I am struggling to run JWplayer in ie 10. It works fine in other browsers (firefox and chrome).

In ie it get following error: `Error loading player:
 No playable sources found`

Following is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                            jwplayer("sample_1").setup({
                                flashplayer: ajax_url + 'jwplayer/jwplayer.flash.swf',
                                file : ajax_url + "uploads/sample.flv",
                                image : "uploads/small.jpg",
                                width : 'auto',
                                height: 'auto'

                            });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your video file has this MIME TYPE - application/octet-stream

It should be - video/mp4