# JW Player can't play mp4 file in IE11

Tags: asp.net, jwplayer6

I'm currently using JWPlayer 6.7 Pro version.
Firefox and Chrome can play but Internet Explorer can't play file. 
Some mp4 files can be played but some of them can't.
Here is my sample page: http://tv.cozumpark.com/jwtest.aspx

> Error Loading Media
>  File could not be played

Answer (score 0):

Your video mime-type seems to be text/plain, it should be video/mp4.

[image]

> Note two very common issues prevent smooth playback of videos in
>   Internet Explorer 9/10. First, you need to set  to
>   prevent triggering IE's quirks mode. Second, your videos must be
>   served with the video/mp4 mimetype or IE will refuse to play them.

Source : [embedding-the-Jwplayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28839/embedding-the-player)

See the [troubleshooting guide](http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/28840/troubleshooting-your-setup) for more common issues.

Check out other similar questions

1. [jw-player-not-playing-mp4-video-format-videos-in-ie9-and-ie10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17187382/jw-player-not-playing-mp4-video-format-videos-in-ie9-and-ie10)
2. [change Mime type of video to make jwplayer work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21847663/changing-video-content-type-mime-type-in-cdn-in-drupal-7)
3. [could-not-play-mp4-with-jw-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16935050/could-not-play-mp4-with-jw-player/)
4. [jwplayer-not-loading-in-ie-10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384054/jwplayer-not-loading-in-ie-10)

**

> Main Problem is wrong mime type for mp4 video, solution is change mime
>   type to appropriate mime type, In your case its mp4 which has mime
>   type video/mp4

**